# where's the memory going in my JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management

I'm working on a 3D game that's built in JavaScript (on top of THREE.js, among other things). We've reached the point of profiling to get our framerate up, and seem to be memory bound.  When I use the JavaScript console in Chrome (ctrl-shift-j), and use that to profile my memory usage, it shows that there are about 200 MB in heap allocations - which would be just fine.  However, when I hit shift-ESC or go to chrome://memory-internals, it reports that I'm using about 1.34 GB of memory, and another 814 MB on the GPU.

To be clear, I don't seem to be *leaking* memory (my footprint is stable), I'm just using a lot of it, and I want to know where it's allocated so I can know where to optimize.

So... obviously, optimizing for what's on the heap isn't going to help me, since it's only about 10% of my memory usage.  How can I get a handle on where all the rest of that memory is being allocated so that I can trim it down to size (besides taking shots in the dark, of course)?

Comment: A-B testing always works better than shots in the dark. keep the serenity prayer at hand as well.